# Clicking on linkbutton, don't want validators to fire

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a profile page with a bunch of textboxes and validators. The validation works fine right now. My issue is that I have added a couple of link buttons that go to different pages. When I click on a linkbutton the validators fire, which I don't want. I just want to go to the next page. 
I tried disbling the validators in the linkbutton click event but it didn't work. How do I stop the validators firing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the CausesValidation atrribute to false on the linkbuttons in the markup:

```
CausesValidation="false"
```

[LinkButton.CausesValidation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.causesvalidation.aspx)

Comment: Yes of course. Thanks. I feel kind of sheepish now since it's so easy. I blame it on post vacation brain and working on a weekend.